# What is the correct way to pass a complex object to a child component using props in React when writing in ES6?

Tags: reactjs

Now that we have ES6 and can use spread I've seen some people write code like this:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <UserProfile {...this.props.user} onClick={this.doSomething} />
    )
  }
}
```

This would set each property of user model as a prop on the UserProfile component. The alternative would be something like this:

```
<UserProfile user={this.props.user} onClick={this.doSomething} />
```

Is one of these approaches considered the better practice? I know which version I'm leaning towards, but I want to know if the community has already landed on doing it one way or the other.

Comment: I don't think there is any "best practice" around this. I'd use whatever is more convenient. Personally I find the second one more explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few quick inputs -

- Obviously, spread is better for props which are not closely related, apart from the fact that all of them are owned by the same component. A complex object is better suited for grouping tightly coupled/grouped properties together, the best example being style.
- Spread gives most clarity, at a glance, I can look at the propTypes to determine the usage. However if you have a lot of props, you should look at the possibility of grouping some of them together.
- The purpose of the component has a role too. A UserProfile component is very specific and it implies several props related to the profile would be required. In this case, I'd prefer complex object when the data model is easily available/constructible in the parent component. However, if you want to support say appearance or behavior related props, like displayLoginHistory etc, which don't tie in with the data model, it'd be better to use spread to keep coherent props.

Comment: That's largely what I was thinking. It makes sense to explicitly pass a complex object if its a domain model, but if you're passing more UI specific stuff (handlers, display flags etc...) and they're conveniently grouped spread them. Want to wait a little while before accepting your answer to see if anyone weighs in with a different perspective. Not sure if that's appropriate for stack overflow but seems reasonable to me.